# How to click a span text using selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I try use xpath element, but he dont see span button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userTabs"]/ul/li[19]').click()
```

What happened?

Log:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="userTabs"]/ul/li[19]/span"}
```

Comment: Any error or screenshot or log?

Comment: tough to tell without seeing the DOM of the page you are scraping. Please post the URL.

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to diagnose your problem.   Please explain what happens when you try to run the code as is, including any error messages.  If you can also provide a link to the page you are scraping that would help to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not provide a link, because. this is a closed network site.
I try to span a button among the tabs and click on it, but instead, among all the tabs, the top one opens, and not the one I specified.

Comment: Without more details the only suggestion i can make is to make sure your xpath path is correct, and possibly pause selenium for a short amount of time to make sure the page has fully rendered before running the find_element method

Comment: Unfortunately none of the options worked.